# How can I run a cross-correlation of 2 signals using a for loop to compare X samples from the data set?

Tags: r, signal-processing, cross-correlation

I am learning cross-correlation and trying to cross correlate 2 sine waves which are slightly offset. I generated some data in Excel and loaded it in to R and I can run a cross correlation of the entire data set (10k rows) but I want to run a cross correlation of a subset of the data (1000 samples). So the cross correlation would run row 1:1000 of sine1 against rows 1:1000 of sine2, then run 2:1002, 3:1003, etc. When it gets to the end 9000:10000, it will stop.

I loaded the data from the Excel file into variables.
sine1, sine2

I used this code

```
for (x in sine_1) {
  if (x == nrow(sine_1)=1000) {
    next
  }
  print(ccf(sine_1, sine_2, type=c("correlation"), ylab="Correlation Value", xlab="Lag"))
}
```

Comment: I do not understand the 1024 in the loop what did you try to do with that?

Comment: 1024 was the number of samples I was using, it should be 1000 - my mistake. Fixed it in the post.

Comment: If you data has 10k elements do you want to print ~9k plots? (10.000 - 1000)? since ccf function prints a plot unless you pass plot=FALSE

Comment: No, not 9k plots. I want to plot the correlation of 9k points on a single plot with a lag of 0. So the correlation of lag=0 on a single plot, 9k times.

Comment: If you want lag==0 (i.e. only one value) then you do not need to use ccf, you use "cor" over a window. Try: `plot(sapply(0:(NROW(sine_1)-1000),  function(i) cor(sine_1[1:1000 + i], sine_2[1:1000 + i])), type="l")`